# jQuery script not working on touch enabled devices

Tags: jquery

Do I need to target a different trigger for touch enabled devices?

I want to pass an id variable in the URL and have the tab on page jump to that tab. It is not working on touch-enabled devices.

Here is the code.

```
$(function() {
    // if hash is set
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var $tabs = $('#tabs'),
        // find tab nav item with matching id
        $target = $tabs.find('.tab-nav li'+window.location.hash);

        // if target exists trigger the set event
        if($target.length) {
            $tabs.trigger('gumby.set', $target.index());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the comma on your 4th line?

Comment: @dckuehn That's just there to declare two variables, `$tabs` and `$target`. It is equivalent to `var $tabs = ...; var $target = ...;`

Comment: Can you use one of the variables as part of the declaration of another within the same statement though?